# How to update a scene without refreshing the scene after receiving data from another class/controller

Tags: javafx

I'm working on a personal weather project that contains Main.fxml, MainController.java, EnterCityDocument.fxml, and EnterCityDocumentController.java.

1. Main.fxml: contains a border-pane and at its center it has a ListView that displays names of cities. It also has a "Add" Button to open a new modal window(EnterCityDocument.fxml) to add a city to its ListView.
2. EnterCityDocument.fxml: has a listView that contains names of cities and a "Select" button to select a city the user wants to display in Main.fxml. When the user clicks the "Select" Button, the modal window (EnterCityDocument.fxml) closes and the Main.fxml continues to run.
3. MainController.java is the parent class of EnterCityDocumentController.java.

I've been looking for passing data from the child class(EnterCityDocumentController.java) to the parent class (MainController.java) and found a way to do it, but all of the methods i've found require to refresh the MainController.java class whenever the user selects a city in EnterCityDocumentController.java.

Is there a way to update the Main.fxml without refreshing the main scene when a new city is added into the listView of the Main.fxml?

Hope my question is clear enough. If you need a further explanation/code, please let me know!

Comment: Just pass the `items` list from the list view in the main view to the `EnterCityDocumentController`. If you add a new city to that list, the `ListView` will automatically update.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is arrange for the new city from the dialog to be added to the list view's backing list. Since you are using `showAndWait()` this is very easy: just define a method in the `EnterCityDocumentController` class that returns the new city, and call it after `showAndWait()`:

```
public class EnterCityDocumentController {

    @FXML
    private TextField cityNameField ;

    // other fields, etc...

    @FXML
    private void okButtonPressed() {
        // just close the window:
        cityNameField.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }

    public City getUserCity() {
        return new City(cityNameField.getText());
    }
}
```

Then in the main controller:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private ListView<City> listView ;

    // handler method:
    @FXML
    public void addNewCity() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(EnterCityDocumentController.class.getResource("EnterCityDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.showAndWait();

        listView.getItems().add(controller.getUserCity());
    }
}
```

Here is a SSCCE:

`app/Main.fxml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.MainController">
   <center>
      <ListView fx:id="listView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addNewElement" text="Add..." BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </Button>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

`app/AddNewElement.fxml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane hgap="5.0" vgap="5.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.AddNewElementController">
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" />
      <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="textField" GridPane.columnSpan="2" />
      <Button defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ok" text="OK" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Button cancelButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancel" text="Cancel" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
   </padding>
</GridPane>
```

`app/AddNewElementController.java`:

```
package app;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class AddNewElementController {

    @FXML
    private TextField textField ;

    private boolean approved ;

    public boolean isApproved() {
        return approved ;
    }

    public String getUserText() {
        return isApproved() ? textField.getText() : null ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void cancel() {
        approved = false ;
        hide(); 
    }

    @FXML
    private void ok() {
        approved = true ;
        hide();
    }

    private void hide() {
        textField.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
}
```

`app/MainController.java`:

```
package app;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView ;

    @FXML
    private void addNewElement() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(AddNewElementController.class.getResource("AddNewElement.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        AddNewElementController controller = loader.getController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.initOwner(listView.getScene().getWindow());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.showAndWait();
        if (controller.isApproved()) {
            listView.getItems().add(controller.getUserText());
        }
    }

}
```

`app/Main.java`:

```
package app;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainController.class.getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

Another, very slightly different approach, is to pass the listview's backing list to the second controller. Then the second controller can add the item directly to the list (and the list view will automatically update, as before). This approach can be used even if you are not using `showAndWait()` (it doesn't rely on the code blocking until the user dismisses the window).

```
package app;

import java.util.List;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class AddNewElementController {

    @FXML
    private TextField textField ;

    private List<String> itemList ;

    public void setItemList(List<String> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList ;
    }


    @FXML
    private void cancel() {
        hide(); 
    }

    @FXML
    private void ok() {
        itemList.add(textField.getText());
        hide();
    }

    private void hide() {
        textField.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
}
```

and

```
package app;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView ;

    @FXML
    private void addNewElement() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(AddNewElementController.class.getResource("AddNewElement.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        AddNewElementController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setItemList(listView.getItems());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.initOwner(listView.getScene().getWindow());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.showAndWait();
    }

}
```

Comment: James, Thank you so much for sharing this information. I didn't think of solving this problem in this way. As you told me, i just made a method getCity() and wrote two lines of codes in main.fxml and it's been solved. Thank you so much, You've made my day!